# Dreamweaver CS5 / XAMPP Local - Cannot seem to connect PHP

Tags: php, xampp, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

Dynamically-related files could not be resolved because of the site definition is not correct for this server. retry | setup

Could someone please assist a junior with this error?  I have included url's of screen shots on current set up and settings.  Thanks for consideration in advance.

![Dreamweaver / XAMPP screenshot of local][1]

http://theautojobs.com/dreamweaver1.PNG

http://theautojobs.com/dreamweaver2.PNG

add a 3 to URL to see a 3rd image (new user and can only post 2 hyperlinks, sorry)

I can post a screenshot on request to server. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your second screenshot, click on Advanced at the top and on the next screen select Server Model to be PHP MySQL